# How do you get java method annotations to work in scala

Tags: java, scala, reflection, scala-java-interop

I've got two projects, a scala project and a java project. My scala project references the java project in the build path. In my java project, i'm declaring the following annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    public String Name();
}
```

In my scala project, I'm annotating some methods. I.e.

```
class MyClass {
    ...
    @MyAnnotation(Name="Blah")
    def myMethod() {
        ...
    }
}
```

In another file somewhere, i'm trying to pull out the annotations.

```
var methods = myClassInstance.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()
var myMethod : Method = null
for (method <- methods) {
  if (method.getName().equals("myMethod")) {
    myMethod = method
  }
}
var annotations = myMethod.getDeclaredAnnotations()
```

Unfortunately, `annotations` is always an empty array. Am I doing something fundamentally wrong or am I just missing something minor? Thanks!

**EDIT**
Originally, I was annotating myMethod with myAnnotation twice, which is incorrect as someone pointed out. It turns out this wasn't the problem. I'm still getting an empty array for `annotations`. No exception is being thrown.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried your code, the problem is that your use @MyAnnotation twice for myMethod, which should raise AnnotationFormatError: Duplicate annotation for class

When i change to use it once, the reflection just retrieves the annotions.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Unfortunately that wasn't the problem. Even with one annotation, i'm still getting an empty array. No exception is being thrown

Comment: How did you get this to work? Can you post an example? Thanks!

Comment: As i said, i just use your posted code. Your posted code raise exceptions (first version), and has compile errors(second version, you should define the type for the line 'var myMethod = null'), after i solve them, it works. And my scala version is 2.9.3

Comment: Thanks for your help. I upgraded from 2.8.3 to 2.9.3 and instead of referencing a java project, i'm mixing java and scala in the same project. seems to be working.